# (Co)Homology: From topology to the rest of mathematics?

Tags: topology, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I can appreciate how (co)homology arose in the context of topology/geometry. Trying to get a handle on the handles of spaces leads one to this idea. It's not obvious, but I can see how this would lead you to homology.

But how does one motivate/understand the expansion into other areas of mathematics? From the geometric/topological point of view simplices seem to be of fundamental importance. Yet, in all other homological theories (groups, sheaves etc.) I don't see simplices. Groups are not broken down into simplices for instance. All I see are these chains of morphisms; how did they take center stage?

Could someone please comment on how it might seem natural to arrive at these different homologies? Or point me in the direction of a reference which discusses how group homology arose from the more geometric simplicial/singular homology theories?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend Weibel’s *History of homological algebra* ([1999](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1721123))([pdf](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/)). He describes many threads, such as roots of group cohomology in Hurewicz’s observation that cohomology of an aspherical space $Y$ depends only on (what we now call cohomology of) its fundamental group $\pi=\pi_1(Y)$:

> [Since] homology and cohomology groups of $Y$ (with coefficients in $A$) were independent of the choice of $Y$, Eilenberg and Mac Lane took them as the definition of $H_n(\pi; A)$ and $H^n(\pi; A)$. To perform computations, Eilenberg and Mac Lane chose a specific abstract simplicial complex $K(\pi)$ for the aspherical space $Y$. (...) Thus one way to calculate the cohomology groups of $\pi$ was to use the cellular cochain complex of $K(\pi)$, whose $n$-chains are functions $f : \pi^q \to A$.

So the simplices are not to be found in $\pi$ but in $K(\pi)$. Another crucial thread is well summarized in the first lines of Chevalley-Eilenberg ([1948](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=24908)):

> [We] give a systematic treatment of the methods by which topological questions concerning compact Lie groups may be reduced to algebraic questions concerning Lie algebras. This reduction proceeds in three steps: (1) replacing questions on homology groups by questions on differential forms. This is accomplished by de Rham’s theorems (which, incidentally, seem to have been conjectured by Cartan for this very purpose); (2) replacing the consideration of arbitrary differential forms by that of invariant differential forms: this is accomplished by using invariant integration on the group manifold; (3) replacing the consideration of invariant differential forms by that of alternating multilinear forms on the Lie algebra of the group.

Answer (score 7):

As a complement to the answer provided by Francois Ziegler, I would add the first three paragraphs of *Homological Algebra* (1956), by Henri Cartan and Samuel Eilenberg:

> During the last decade the methods of algebraic topology have invaded extensively the domain of pure algebra, and initiated a number of internal revolutions. The purpose of this book is to present a unified account of these developments and to lay the foundations of a full-fledged theory.
>
> The invasion of algebra has occurred on three fronts through the
> construction of cohomology theories for groups, Lie algebras, and
> associative algebras. The three subjects have been given independent
> but parallel developments. We present herein a single cohomology (and
> also a homology) theory which embodies all three; each is obtained
> from it by a suitable specialization.
>
> This unification possesses all the usual advantages. One proof replaces three. In addition an
> interplay takes place among the three specializations; each enriches
> the other two.